# Codename One: understand warnings and SecurityException after upgrading from JDK23 to JDK27

Tags: codenameone

On May 2018, Codename One was moved to Android API Level 27.
Previously I loaded in the store the version 0.1 of an app built with Codename One, with the Android API Level 23 (that was the previous default).

Google is forcing all its developers to upgrade the APPs to the newer API before the 1st November 2018, that's why I submitted to the store, few days ago, the same app, without any code modification, built with the last version of Codename One.

Today I received the following crash protection report. **My question is an help to understand all the warnings and the `java.lang.SecurityException`**. My app doesn't require any special permission and don't ask permissions to the user during the running (it's a very simple app). Before upgrading the app to the API Level 27 I never got these warnings and this exception.

```
[EDT] 0:0:0,1 - Codename One revisions: 38629bb7dc1724677b602b7cf175bee9bf0d67c8

[EDT] 0:0:0,4 - WARNING: Theme sets the commandBehavior constant which is deprecated.  Please update the theme to NOT include this theme constant.  Using commandBehavior may cause your app to perform in unexpected ways.  In particular, using SIDE command behavior in conjunction with Toolbar.setOnTopSideMenu(true) may result in runtime exceptions.
[EDT] 0:0:0,6 - WARNING: Display.setCommandBehavior() is deprecated, Using it may result in unexpected behaviour. In particular, using COMMAND_BEHAVIOR_SIDE_NAVIGATION in conjunction with Toolbar.setOnTopSideMenu(true) may result in runtime errors.
[EDT] 0:0:0,11 - STARTING of the app "Giorno per giorno" version 0.2
[EDT] 0:0:0,12 - Platform: Unknown
[EDT] 0:0:0,13 - Platform Name: and
[EDT] 0:0:0,15 - OS: Android
[EDT] 0:0:0,17 - OS Version: 8.0.0
[EDT] 0:0:0,19 - Display Width: 1080
[EDT] 0:0:0,20 - Display Height: 2150
[EDT] 0:0:0,22 - Device density: DENSITY_HD
[EDT] 0:0:0,23 - mese: 10
[EDT] 0:0:0,24 - giorno del mese: 19
[EDT] 0:0:0,36 - I'm trying to open the file /giorno-293.txt
[EDT] 0:0:0,38 - File opened successfully
[EDT] 0:0:0,38 - isNativeShareSupported: true
[EDT] 0:0:0,874 - Exception: java.lang.SecurityException - Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10400000 cmp=com.huawei.android.launcher/.powersavemode.PowerSaveModeLauncher (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{e69f9b7 13566:cloud.amoremio.app.daybyday/u0a110} (pid=13566, uid=10110) not exported from uid 10072
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10400000 cmp=com.huawei.android.launcher/.powersavemode.PowerSaveModeLauncher (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{e69f9b7 13566:cloud.amoremio.app.daybyday/u0a110} (pid=13566, uid=10110) not exported from uid 10072
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1946)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1892)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:4373)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1631)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4751)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4691)
    at com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneActivity.startActivityForResult(CodenameOneActivity.java:576)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5112)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5080)
    at com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneActivity.startActivity(CodenameOneActivity.java:590)
    at com.codename1.impl.android.d.W(AndroidImplementation.java:1311)
    at com.codename1.s.q.o(Display.java:1546)
    at com.codename1.s.ab.c(MenuBar.java:1413)
    at com.codename1.s.aj.c(SideMenuBar.java:704)
    at com.codename1.s.u.c(Form.java:2748)
    at com.codename1.s.q.a(Display.java:2015)
    at com.codename1.s.q.j(Display.java:1043)
    at com.codename1.s.q.i(Display.java:961)
    at com.codename1.s.ai.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.b$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
[EDT] 0:0:0,877 - Exception in Giorno per giorno version 0.2
[EDT] 0:0:0,877 - OS and
[EDT] 0:0:0,878 - Error java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10400000 cmp=com.huawei.android.launcher/.powersavemode.PowerSaveModeLauncher (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{e69f9b7 13566:cloud.amoremio.app.daybyday/u0a110} (pid=13566, uid=10110) not exported from uid 10072
[EDT] 0:0:0,878 - Current Form null
[EDT] 0:0:0,879 - Exception: java.lang.SecurityException - Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10400000 cmp=com.huawei.android.launcher/.powersavemode.PowerSaveModeLauncher (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{e69f9b7 13566:cloud.amoremio.app.daybyday/u0a110} (pid=13566, uid=10110) not exported from uid 10072
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10400000 cmp=com.huawei.android.launcher/.powersavemode.PowerSaveModeLauncher (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{e69f9b7 13566:cloud.amoremio.app.daybyday/u0a110} (pid=13566, uid=10110) not exported from uid 10072
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1946)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1892)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:4373)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1631)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4751)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4691)
    at com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneActivity.startActivityForResult(CodenameOneActivity.java:576)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5112)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5080)
    at com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneActivity.startActivity(CodenameOneActivity.java:590)
    at com.codename1.impl.android.d.W(AndroidImplementation.java:1311)
    at com.codename1.s.q.o(Display.java:1546)
    at com.codename1.s.ab.c(MenuBar.java:1413)
    at com.codename1.s.aj.c(SideMenuBar.java:704)
    at com.codename1.s.u.c(Form.java:2748)
    at com.codename1.s.q.a(Display.java:2015)
    at com.codename1.s.q.j(Display.java:1043)
    at com.codename1.s.q.i(Display.java:961)
    at com.codename1.s.ai.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.b$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

Comment: Are you invoking minimize early in the application lifecycle or when it's in the background?

Comment: No, I don't use `minimizeApplication()`. The app is very minimal, it simply shows a text according to the day of the year. It reads the text from a txt files. It's composed by only small class. The full source is here: https://github.com/jsfan3/GiornoPerGiorno/blob/master/src/cloud/amoremio/app/daybyday/Guide.java

Comment: How do you reproduce this? Did you run through Android Studio or is this something that happens from the build server? How do you trigger it?

Comment: I received that crash protection report by email. The crash happened yesterday to one of about thousand app users, so I cannot reproduce this issue. Maybe it's not important, however it's strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the Huawei launcher. When a user presses the back button in the applications main form we minimize the application by default (as is the convention in Android). The minimize method is implemented as such on Android:

```
public boolean minimizeApplication() {
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startMain.putExtra("WaitForResult", Boolean.FALSE);
    getContext().startActivity(startMain);
    return true;
}
```

This essentially asks the system to go back "home". It doesn't require permissions or anything specific but it seems Huawei misconfigured their activity and this fails. I think this just means backing out of the app on these devices will fail. The user can probably still use the home button itself instead of the back button.

Unfortunately it seems Huawei don't have a public bug reporting system. Hopefully they'll fix this issue or a workaround will emerge.

Comment: I cannot test the Back button on a Huawei device with Android 8, because I haven't one in my hands or in the device farm I'm using. However, if the problem is the back button, I hope that assigning a function to the back button is a solution. In my case, for example: `hi.getToolbar().setBackCommand(Command.create(null, null, e -> {this.previousDay();}), Toolbar.BackCommandPolicy.NEVER);`

Comment: The problem is in the call to minimize which on the main form only defaults to minimizing the app. This can workaround it but it might also produce the undesireable effect on other Android devices where they don't match platform conventions (back in the main view should minimize).